# How to solve selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to code a bot that will automate a login on a certain page using selenium. I keep getting the same error, and I don't know how to fix it. Please help :=)

Here's the code:

```
# Importing everything #
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# PATH + Driver Setup #
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# Getting All Requirements #
driver.get("https://ytmonster.net/login")
time.sleep(5)
imputUsername = driver.find_element(By.ID, "inputUsername")
imputPassword = driver.find_element(By.ID, "inputPassword")
linkClick = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn btn-success")

# Executing script #
imputUsername.send_keys("mymail@gmail.com")
imputPassword.send_keys("mypassword")
linkClick.click
```

And here is the error that I get:

```
C:\Users\Xera\Desktop\YtMonster Bot.py:9: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51847/devtools/browser/a848e7ed-d31d-4415-96c5-1a28a4729a17
[8664:1220:0815/155348.366:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:53:48.364] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Xera\Desktop\YtMonster Bot.py", line 16, in <module>
    linkClick = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn btn-success")
  File "C:\Users\Xera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 856, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Xera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 434, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Xera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn btn-success"}
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00CA78B3+2193587]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C40681+1771137]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B541A8+803240]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B824A0+992416]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B8273B+993083]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BAF7C2+1177538]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B9D7F4+1103860]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BADAE2+1170146]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B9D5C6+1103302]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B777E0+948192]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B786E6+952038]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F50CB2+2738370]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F421B8+2678216]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D317AA+512954]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D30856+509030]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C4743B+1799227]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C4BB68+1817448]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C4BC55+1817685]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C55230+1856048]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x766A6739+25]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x779F90AF+1215]
        RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x779F907D+1165]
```

How can I fix this? I tried everything but didn't find any answers... Thanks again for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass multiple classnames as argument using [`By.CLASS_NAME`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#selenium.webdriver.common.by.By.CLASS_NAME) as:

```
find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "classname1 classname2")
```

---

### Solution

To automate the login process on the [webpage](https://www.ytmonster.net/login) you can use [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://ytmonster.net/login'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#inputUsername"))).send_keys("Xera@stackoverflow.com")
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#inputPassword").send_keys("XeraXera")
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-success").click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://ytmonster.net/login'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='inputUsername']"))).send_keys("Xera@stackoverflow.com")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='inputPassword']").send_keys("XeraXera")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-success']").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: ytmonster]

Answer (score 0):

This is because your page elements get changed after you manipulate it using Selenium. Try other ways to access the desired element such as [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). Selecting `by` `class` often causes this exception as the class of your html elements can change. For example, once a tab is clicked, the class can change to something like: `tab-button active`, while prior to the clicking, it was something like: `tab-button`.
I recommend using [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). It is very powerful as it enhances your ability to access items in a relative way from each other. You can for example say I want the i-th children of my first row inside a `table` inside `body` inside `html` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of accomplishing your task:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()

# firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1500")
# firefox_options.add_argument("--height=500")
# firefox_options.headless = True

driverService = Service('chromedriver/geckodriver')

browser = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=firefox_options)

url = 'https://ytmonster.net/login'

browser.get(url)

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='inputUsername']"))).send_keys('my_great_username')
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='inputPassword']"))).send_keys('my really bad password')
print('wrote in my user and pass')
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Login']"))).click()
print('clicked the login button!')
```

The setup is Firefox /geckodriver on Linux, however you can adapt it to your own system, just observe the imports, and the part after defining the browser/driver.
Selenium docs:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/